# Seismograph, but a weird scaling effect happens

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I want to create a seismograph-like curve writing like here: https://youtu.be/7nnB1EVvGzU?t=39

[For tryout, I use the wiggle random values like in the blender noise modifier. Later, I wanna apply sound data etc.]

In my first version, where my pointer (small red square) is constantly moving along the x-axis (starting at x=0, from left to right), it works fine.

[image]

But I want to write new values always at the beginning (x=0) and let go the rest along the x axis, like a seismograph (like in the video link above).

So for every new point written on the x-axis, I move the whole curve one point to the right on the x-axis. Thereby every new point is written at x=0, and now the whole curve is moving from left to right. But then it strangely creates a kind of scaling, the curve frequency becomes lower and lower.

You see here that the curve is at the right rather smooth and dense, but as time goes by (newer points written on x=0), the curve towards the left becomes more and more stretched, which is not wanted.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Update: Solution found. Since the curve is re-written every frame, one has only to re-shift it generally by a value.

[image]

Comment: Seems the problem is transforming a spline / curve which is constantly getting bigger and bigger. To get a constant shift on x-axis, one has to decrease the transform speed over time. Anyone knows an exact formula therefore..?